# Monitoring a Windows network with graphical tools

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, network-monitor, network-administration

Our small company is sometimes experiencing real slow down issues on our Internet connection. The problem is we don't have any idea where it comes from.

I wanted to be able to monitor computers' network usage to spot where the issue comes from, but I haven't found a good software to do so. I can use `Wireshark` but I would like to view the data in a graphical way.

Other software I tried are only trials or limited versions, so it's not really long term solutions.

Almost all our computers are using Windows (XP, Vista, 8 or 10) and we have two Allied Telesis switches AT-GS950/48.

I'm looking for a solution that does not imply to install an agent on every computer.

EDIT :

I don't know which kind of data it is best to monitor. Since I want to know if the switches are overloaded, I would say Bytes/sec.
I don't know if the switch have a monitor port, but it is possible to configure them with SNMP.

Comment: Which data? Bytes/second, packets/second, number of connections, ping time, TCP error rate, traffic sorted by protocol, ... ? Do those switches have a monitor port? Wireshark is certainly *the* tool to analyze slow networks.

Comment: @ThomasWeller see my edits. I know Wireshark is good but I don't understand everything there since I'm no network guy, I'm a developper originally...

Comment: Then, why would you as a developer track down that slowlyness and not delegate the task to your admin?

Comment: IMHO you should first find out how to approach this kind of issue. Such a question could e.g. be asked on SuperUser. Once you have an idea on *what* you want to do, you can ask for tools to support you (here). Such a slowlyness can occur due to wrong DNS settings, wrong DHCP configuration, wrong routing, too much traffic, malware, hardware issues (e.g. broken cables), incorrect IPv6 configuration. In many of those cases, a graphical tool just tells you nothing. Also: IMHO you need to know about monitor ports for sure, since in a switched network you can only capture all traffic on such a port.

Comment: Suggested courses (use the free one month evaluation): https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wireshark-introduction, https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wireshark-protocol-analysis-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what I was looking for. [Spiceworks Network Monitor](http://www.spiceworks.com/free-network-monitoring-management-software/) Is installed as a server on a machine and keeps track of various networking activity.

Thanks anyway to those who took the time to answer and help me.

Answer (score 0):

[10-Strike Bandwidth Monitor](http://www.10-strike.com/bandwidth-monitor/) can monitor the traffic usage on all your machines via WMI if you have admin rights on them.
If you fail to get the traffic data from a WMI sensor, try to provide the admin username in the pc_name\username or domain_name\username format. This helped me the last time I used the tool. Or read their FAQ on how to run the monitoring service with admin rights.

The program can monitor traffic and network bandwidth on switches via SNMP as well but I suppose that using WMI is enough for your task.

The program can also display the error rate and other network interface parameters from remote machines in one place. A 30-day trial is available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am looking for a free products, as we don't really have any budget to spend on it (not my decision...)

Comment: If I remember well, they offered 3 free sensors forever in their trial. You can also try to solve your task in 30 days while the trial version is not limited. :)